# Remote forward() invocation of ProcessorContext throws NPE

Tags: java, apache-kafka, nullpointerexception, apache-kafka-streams

I use Apache Kafka Streams the Processor API.

I create a remote object that extends the UnicastRemoteObject inside the StateStore of the Processor.

When the `init(ProcessorContext)` method of the Processor (which extends the AbstractProcessor) of my topology is called I put a ProcessorContext reference inside that remote Object.

```
public void init(ProcessorContext processorContext){
  super.init(processorContext);
  this.myStore = (MyCustomStore<String, String>)context().getStateStore("mystore");
  this.myStore.getRemoteObject().setProcessorContext(processorContext);
}
```

If I access the ProcessorContext **only remotely** and use the `forward` method to send records to a sink processor it works fine. And if I access the ProcessorContext **only locally** to send records with `forward` it works fine, too.

If I access the ProcessorContext both locally and remotely to use `forward` I have NPE.  I used a synchronized method in which `foward` is called because I thought that two different threads try to access ProcessorContext at the same time but the NPE insists.

It seems to me that somehow the same thread calls forward at the same time 
both locally and remotely and that throws NPE.

The message is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:114)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
        at StateMessageBean.sendMessage(StateMessageBean.java:109)
        at StateMessageBean.subroundEnded(StateMessageBean.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.subroundEnded(Unknown Source)
        at CoordinatorProcessor.collectIncreaseOfC(CoordinatorProcessor.java:332)
        at CoordinatorProcessor.process(CoordinatorProcessor.java:119)
        at CoordinatorProcessor.process(CoordinatorProcessor.java:25)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:302)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:94)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:409)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndMaybeCommit(StreamThread.java:964)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:832)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
```

The two methods that I call remotely and locally are:

```
//remote method
@Override
public void subroundEnded()
{
    PhiMessage newPhiMessage = new PhiMessage();
    newPhiMessage.setSiteId(this.siteId);
    newPhiMessage.setCurrentRound(this.currentRound);
    newPhiMessage.setCurrentSubround(this.currentSubround);
    newPhiMessage.setPhi(this.phi);

    byte[] byteNewPhiMessage = SerializationUtils.serialize(newPhiMessage);
    this.processorContext.forward("PhiMessage",  byteNewPhiMessage);
}

//local method
public  void sendIncrease()
{

  IncreaseMessage increaseMessage = new IncreaseMessage();
  increaseMessage.setCurrentRound(this.currentRound);
  increaseMessage.setCurrentSubround(this.currentSubround);
  increaseMessage.setIncrease(this.increase);
  byte[] byteIncreaseMessage = SerializationUtils.serialize(increaseMessage);
  this.processorContext.forward("IncreaseMessage",  byteIncreaseMessage);

}
```

Comment: `StateMessageBean.sendMessage` sent something that was null?

Comment: Inside StateMessageBean.sendMessage there was the processorContext.forward method. This line throws NPE.

Comment: Yes, but what are you forwarding? Please show that code

Comment: I will show but I would like to ask if the main concept is right, that is I have byte array serde and I serialize/deserialize custom objects according to the key of the topic record which is a string.  Is there a problem with that?

Comment: Why not use StringSerde if your data is strings?

Comment: String is only the key, the value is byte array